# is_dir is giving me directories as not directory

Tags: php

```
$dir=array("EN","EN/Products","EN/Equipment");  
if(is_dir($dir)){  
    foreach($dir as $d):  
        echo ("<b style='color:red'>$d</b> is a directory<br/>");  
    endforeach;  
}  
else{  
    foreach($dir as $d):
        echo ("<b style='color:red'>$d</b> is not a directory<br/>");
    endforeach;
}
```

all the array values are Folders having some pages what is happening is that am trying to go with the else as these array values are real folders.

Here is my output value

> EN is not a directory
>
> EN/Products is not a directory
>
> EN/Equipment is not a directory

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: `$dir` is an array and `is_dir()` only takes a string!

Comment: is_dir want a single string (from php online guide). http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: try an `if(in_array())` type of thing.

Comment: if this is valid code, then if you're on a Linux platform, `EN` is not the same as `en`.

Comment: Thank you Rizier123 &  Fred -ii- as your comments really helped finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($dir as $d):
    parse_str($d);
    if(is_dir($d)){
        echo ("<b style='color:red'>$d</b> is a directory<br/>");
    }
    else{
        echo ("<b style='color:red'>$d</b> is not a directory<br/>");
    }
endforeach;
```

This is what i figured as am not a PHP developer but am just trying to add a very small thing to a runing application, what i found is that its easily to parse the array into string!!!

Thanks a lot for your ideas as they are the ones led me to the answer.

Comment: You got my vote, good job *cheers*